# Are there proper infinite power series in $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$?

Tags: functions, power-series

Are there infinite power series

$f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z, \hspace{.5cm} f(n)=\sum_{k\in S\subset \mathbb Z} a_k n^k,$

where $f$ isn't polynomial, i.e. the coefficients $a_k$ (which can be from all of $\mathbb C$ if you will) do not just become trivial? I guess this is the case as I expect there to be doable series representations for interpolations of stuff like the factorial, which is well defined at least on $\mathbb N$.

Now moreover, are there such series where a finite subset $F\subset \mathbb Z$ in the domain is fixed by $f$? I got interested in this because then the class of $f^m$ are all permutations on $K$, but the functions might be nontrivial on the rest of the domain.

Comment: Not what you are expecting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number.

Comment: I suppose that $g$ should be $f$...

Comment: Here is a related result. For each function $f: \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{Z}$, there is a unique family $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbf{N}}$ of coefficients such that $f(n) = \sum_k a_k \binom{n}{k}$. The coefficients $a_k$ are given by $a_k = (\Delta^k f)(0)$, where $\Delta f(n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: right, $f$, thx.